# Add value to signal

Tags: qt, qt-signals

This is the task: i catch signal from

```
QNetworkAccessManager* manager= new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(parse_data_request(QNetworkReply*)));
connect(manager, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished, manager,
&QNetworkAccessManager::deleteLater,Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

And i want send to slot parse_data_request int variable with QNetworkReply* like this:

```
QNetworkAccessManager* manager= new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*,int)), this, SLOT(parse_data_request(QNetworkReply*,int)));
connect(manager, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished, manager,
&QNetworkAccessManager::deleteLater,Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

How can i do it?

Comment: What does the extra `int` parameter represent?  Is its value known when you make the `connect` call?

Comment: Yes, its exist value, count of request, and i want know which request return finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Qt5 (which you appear to be) then you can use a lambda as the target of the connection...

```
int request_id = ...;
QNetworkAccessManager* manager= new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
connect(manager, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished, this,
        [this, request_id](QNetworkReply *reply)
        {
            parse_data_request(reply, request_id);
        });
connect(manager, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished, manager, &QNetworkAccessManager::deleteLater,Qt::QueuedConnection);
```